# Convert Image to Rulinalg Matrix in Rust

Tags: arrays, image-processing, rust

I am learning Rust and I want to perform some basic image operations. I am currently reading my images like this: `image::open("path/to/img.jpg").unwrap()` by using the [`image`](https://crates.io/crates/image) crate.

The problem is that I want my image to be in a specific 2d format where there are `N=height*weight` rows and 3 columns (one for each color). I have found the [`rulinalg`](https://crates.io/crates/rulinalg) crate but I cannot create a `rulinalg::matrix::Matrix` from the `DynamicImage` object. I have tried the following:

```rust
// Normalize to [0, 1]
let (width, height) = img.dimensions();
let n = width*height;
let tmp = img.as_rgb8().unwrap().to_vec().iter().map(|&e| e as f32 / 255.0).collect::<Vec<f32>>();
let mat = Matrix::new(n, 3, tmp);
```

So now I have a matrix of `n` rows and 3 columns but I am not sure if it is a correct representation. By that, I mean that I am not sure that the first pixel consists of the values `mat[[0, 0]], mat[[n, 0]], mat[[n*2, 0]]`.

So, in order to test it, I thought I should try to recreate the image by using the `mat` matrix with the following code:

```rust
let mut img_buf = image::ImageBuffer::new(width, height);
for i in 0..mat.rows() {
    let color0 = (mat[[i, 0]] * 255.0) as u8;
    let color1 = (mat[[i, 1]] * 255.0) as u8;
    let color2 = (mat[[i, 2]] * 255.0) as u8;
    let x = i as u32 /height;
    let y = i as u32 - x*height;
    let pixel = img_buf.get_pixel_mut(x, y);
    // let image = *pixel;
    *pixel = image::Rgb([color0, color1, color2]);

}
img_buf.save("./tmp.jpg").unwrap();
```

But the output is only noise (even though the color structure seems to be kept the same). I have tried a lot of things and nothing seems to work. I also tried to find similar "projects" on github but the only relevant thing I found was applying filters to images which simply called functions from the `image` crate.

#### Desired Workflow

So, what I want is the following:

1. Read image from path (3d image since it is not grayscale)
2. Convert image to a Matrix (`rulinalg::matrix::Matrix`)
3. Apply functions such as: element-wise logarith/exponential/square-root, axis-wise sum/max and other similar functions (numpy equivalent: `np.log(arr), np.exp(arr), np.sqrt(arr), np.sum(arr, axis=0), np.amax(arr, axis=0)`)
4. Save the modified matrix as an image.

#### Reason

My goal is to perform image segmentation and reduce the colors of the image (by clustering).

#### Question

Does anyone have any idea or pointers of how I can do the above in rust?

Comment: I suspect that you have rows and columns switched: shouldn't `x` be `i % width` and `y` be `i / width`?

Comment: Well, you are right! I was in this problem for hours and didn't even think of changing the axes... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Following @Jmb's comment, the reason that the output image was noise was because I have mistaken the axes.

I just want to post what I did in case there is someone else who wants to do something similar. Do keep in mind though that I am new to rust and so I may have made some mistakes.

#### Using `rulinalg`

If you want to use the `rulinalg` crate, the following should work (version `0.4.2`):

```rust
let img = image::open("path/to/img.jpg").unwrap();
let (width, height) = img.dimensions();

let n = (width * height) as usize;
// Normalize image pixels to [0, 1]
let tmp = img.as_rgb8().unwrap().to_vec().iter().map(|&e| e as f32 / 255.0).collect::<Vec<f32>>();
// Reduce dimensions
let mut mat = Matrix::new(n, 3, tmp);
// Change the array values by using some other method
mat = my_processing_method(mat);
// Image buffer for the new image
let mut img_buf = image::ImageBuffer::new(width, height);
for i in 0..mat.rows() {
    // Move back to the [0, 255] range
    let color0 = (mat[[i, 0]] * 255.0) as u8;
    let color1 = (mat[[i, 1]] * 255.0) as u8;
    let color2 = (mat[[i, 2]] * 255.0) as u8;
    let x = i as u32 % width;
    let y = i as u32 / width;
    let pixel = img_buf.get_pixel_mut(x, y);
    *pixel = image::Rgb([color0, color1, color2]);

}
// Save the updated image
img_buf.save("path/to/new/image.jpg").unwrap();
```

#### Using `ndarray` and `ndarray_image`:

For ease, you may also use the `ndarray-image` (version `0.3.0`) in order to open the image and save it in an `ndarray::Array3` (3d array). If you want to use `ndarray` instead of the `rulinalg` crate then you can do the following:

```rust
use ndarray::{Array2, Dim};
use ndarray_image::{open_image, save_image, Colors};

let img = open_image("path/to/img.jpg", Colors::Rgb).expect("unable to open input image");
// A vector of 3 spots for each dimension
let sh = img.shape();
let (height, width, colors) = (sh[0] as u32, sh[1] as u32, sh[2]);
let n = (width * height) as usize;
// The dimension of the new 2d array
let new_dim = Dim([n, 3]);
// Normalize to [0, 1] and convert to 1d vector
let img_vec = img.map(|&e| e as f32 / 255_f32).into_raw_vec();
// Convert the 1d vector to the 2d ndarray::Array2
let img_arr = Array2::from_shape_vec(new_dim, img_vec).ok().unwrap();
let mut img_buf = image::ImageBuffer::new(width, height);
for i in 0..img_arr.nrows() {
    let color0 = (img_arr[[i, 0]] * 255.0) as u8;
    let color1 = (img_arr[[i, 1]] * 255.0) as u8;
    let color2 = (img_arr[[i, 2]] * 255.0) as u8;
    let x = i as u32 % width;
    let y = i as u32 / width;
    let pixel = img_buf.get_pixel_mut(x, y);
    *pixel = image::Rgb([color0, color1, color2]);
}
img_buf.save("path/to/new/image.jpg").unwrap();
```

Hope this is helpful!